# Setup Eclipse for OpenFire server

Tags: eclipse, xmpp, openfire

I want to add configurations to the OpenFire server.
[I downloaded Openfire 3.9.2 from](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp)
When I try to Open project eclipse says no project found, because it has no .project and .classpath and .settings file.

What I should do to run openfire library project in eclipse, I am using eclipse EE edition.