# building a xmpp server

Tags: node.js, xmpp

I want to write android chat based application.
So intead of using gcm I want to extend the existing xmpp server.
So i tried with [xmpp node js server](https://github.com/node-xmpp/server). But all the features are not implemented in that server .So i thought extending the nodejs xmpp server.

1. Are they any better docs or tutorials to understand more about xmpp server.
2. if not nodejs xmpp server, how can i extend jabber or any other xmpp server.

I googled a lot but I didn't find any docs related to extending a jabber-like server.

Comment: I suggest to use an [existing XMPP server](http://xmpp.org/software/servers.html), there is plenty of already done XMPP servers...

Comment: can I extend or change the exisiting xmpp server code.

Comment: Are there are servers which are written in java or nodejs, as I didn't find any ?

Comment: Openfire is written in java: http://igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp, https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire

Answer (score 1):

You can use Openfire server source code from Github:

https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire

You can build openfire source in IntelliJ if you are already familiar with Android Studio. Here is some insight:

https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/can-i-develop-openfire-using-ide-tool-intellij-idea/76503

Also you can open Openfire source code in Eclipse:

[Setup Eclipse for OpenFire server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941694/setup-eclipse-for-openfire-server)